# Is this a circular reference inside the closure?

Tags: javascript, closures, circular-reference

I was wondering if `self` cause a circular reference by being captured by `add`. And will this be a problem for a garbage collector of an old browser.

```
var fun = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.value = 0;
    this.add = function(number) {
        self.value += number;
    };
};
fun.prototype.inc = function() {
    this.value++;
};
fun.prototype.dec = function() {
    this.value--;
};
```

Comment: thats a common enough pattern that you don't have to worry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering if `self` cause a circular reference by being captured by `add`.

Yes.

> And will this be a problem for a garbage collector of an old browser.

No. Not even an ancient one.